# How to optimize this NHibernate 3.2 linq query

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Let's say I have the following 2 entities. (Please forgive any code typos, I am being a bit of an insomniac and and typing this from memory)

```
public class Foo {
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual int Version {get;set;}
   public virtual string SomeProp {get;set;}
   public virtual Bar Bar {get;set;}
}

public class Bar {
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual int Version {get;set;}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

//Fluent Mappings
public class FooMapping :ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        Id (f => f.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Version(f => f.Version);
        Map(f=> f.SomeProp).Column("fooprop1");
        References(f => f.Bar).Column("foobarid").Not.Null();
    }
}

public class BarMapping :ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMapping()
    {
        Id (b => b.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Version(b => b.Version);
        Map(b => b.name).Column("barname");
    }
}
```

when I write a query like this:

```
var query = from f in Session.Query<Foo>()
            where f.Bar.Id == 5
            select new {f.Id, f.SomeProp};
```

I notice that NHibernate generates a sql query with an inner join to the Bar table, and then does it's where clause on the Bar table's Id. I suspect it does this to ensure that the bar.id=5 is a valid bar id?

My question is how can I tell NHibernate to let me query the foo table alone against the foo.foobarid column.  Something like this:

`SELECT f.id, f.prop1 FROM foo f WHERE f.foobarid = 5`

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this optimization is not implemented for Linq (it's documented and working for HQL).

But you can use a `Bar` object for the comparison as a workaround. `session.load()` will not hit the DB, so there is no additional performace cost for that.

```
var bar = Session.Load<Bar>(5);
var query = from f in Session.Query<Foo>()
            where f.Bar == bar
            select new {f.Id, f.SomeProp};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It worked perfectly!  Hopefully later versions of NH-Linq will use this optimization, but this works for me right now.